# Can my unshared documents on Mendeley be removed for infringement on copyright or other intellectual property rights?

Tags: pdf, mendeley

Also, can documents shared with private groups only be removed? http://www.mendeley.com/copyright/ does not specify it.

Comment: This presumes that Mendeley proactively looks for infringing material. More than likely they just respond to DMCA requests, which would require that someone else can see your content and complains about it. But, really, this is a question to ask Mendeley.

Comment: I'm not sure that Mendeley would openly say "yeah go ahead uploaded copyrighted materials" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unshared documents on Mendeley may be removed for infringement on copyright or other intellectual property rights.